# Javassist - CannotCompileException: constructor/method declaration not found

Tags: java, android, javassist

I've got the following class which i want to use in my generated code with Javassist.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private String someString;
    private Object someValue;

    public SomeClass() {}

    public SomeClass(String someString, Object someValue) {
        this.someString = someString;
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(Object someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }
```

In Javassist i analyse some classes and their fields and then try to instatiate my SomeClass-class. But i get the following error for each field which has another type then `java.lang.Object`.

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] setSomeValue(int) not found in com.test.SomeClass
```

and

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] setSomeValue(double) not found in com.test.SomeClass
```

and so on. The same happens when i try to use the constructor.

Why this doesn't work?

By the way, Javassist is used in conjunction with Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate between primitive datatypes and Classes:
A primitive datatype (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, `char`) cannot be used like a class (like `Object` in your case), in order to be able to use them as `Objects`, you need wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Short`, `Long`, etc.).

This is a basic of java, you should get yourself informed about primitive datatypes in java online: The [Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) may help you out.

You might also ask yourself why primitive datatypes are even neccessary when there are wrapper classes. You can find answers to that on [this Stack Overflow question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203970/when-to-use-primitive-vs-class-in-java).